# c++ implicit conversion of string to char* matches wrong function signature

Tags: c++, char, stdstring, implicit-conversion

I am writing a program which is supposed to handle both c strings (char*) and c++ strings (std::string).  I have isolated by concern to the example below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void hello(std::string s) {
    std::cout << "STRING FUNCTION" << std::endl;
}

void hello(char* c) {
    std::cout << "CHAR FUNCTION" << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    hello("ambiguous");
    hello((std::string)"string");
    hello((char*)"charp");

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile this program, I get the warning:

```
test.cpp:14: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’
```

regarding the first call to `hello`.
Running the program gives:

```
CHAR FUNCTION
STRING FUNCTION
CHAR FUNCTION
```

showing that the first call to `hello` is matching the signature `hello(char* c)`.

My question is, if, as a c++ program, a string literal, (`"ambiguous"`) is a std::string, why would it be cast to a `char*` and then match the function `hello(char* c)` rather than staying as a std::string and matching `hello(std::string s)`?

I know I can pragma or -Wsomething out the warning (and that I can cast char* to string without concern), but I want to know why the compiler would even bother doing this cast and if there is a way to tell it not to.  I am compiling with g++ 4.4.3.

Thank you.

Comment: A string literal is not an `std::string`. It has type `const char[N]`.

Comment: string literal, (`"ambiguous"`) is **not** a std::string.  It follows the same convention as C strings.

Comment: In case it hasn't come across yet, change `char *` to `const char *`.

Comment: I see.  My misunderstanding along with the warning message using the phrase `string constant` rather than `char[]` made me believe otherwise.

Comment: Also, the reason you're getting the `test.cpp:14: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’` warning is because you're converting a string literal into a `char *` rather than a `const char *`. The compiler is warning you, because `hello(char *c)` is free to write to the address pointed to by `c`. Never mind that your function doesn't write to `c`; the compiler knows that it *can*, because `c` is non-`const`. String literals should be regarded as read-only; writing to them results in undefined behavior (i.e. may work on some hardware but not on others).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

String literals like `"ambiguous"` are not of type `std::string`. `std::string` is a library only type, with no language magic whatsoever. The type of a string literal is actually `const char[N]`, where `N` is the length of the literal.

For historical reasons (backward compatibility) string literals will implicitely convert to `char*` (violating const-correctness). This builtin conversion is prefered to the "user defined" conversion to `std::string`, which is why it calls the `char*` function and gives you the warning.

If you change the signature of `hello` to `hello(const char* c)` it will probably not give you a warning anymore (but still won't call the `std::string` version, to do that you need a manual cast).

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong : "as a c++ program, a string literal, ("ambiguous") is a std::string"

Comment: It's good to know the OP is wrong, but it'd be even better to know what the right answer is :)

Answer (score 0):

("ambiguous") is not a std::string, it is an array of characters.

That's why its calling void hello(char* c).